# @UsesPipes() Validation Decorator Is Not Invoked During Testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

Controller:

```
@Controller
export class MyController
{
  ...
  @Post()
  @UsesPipes(new MyValidationPipe())
  async Create(
          @Body() body: postBodyDto
          @Request() request: Request
          @File() file: File
        )
  {
    // My Implementation
  }
}
```

Validation Pipe:

```
@Injectable()
export class PostPublicationDmValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  console.log("hello world! I am invoked!");
  private readonly logger = new Logger(PostPublicationDmValidationPipe.name);
  transform(value: any, metaData: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (value.type != 'x') { throw new Error('...') }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
describe('test MyController Create method', () => 
{
  test("should throw error when type is not x, async () => 
  {
    const myPostBody: PostBodyDto = { 'type':'y', ... };
    const mockedFile = { filename: '...', mimetype: '...', buffer: ..., ...} as unknown as File
    const mockedRequest = { headers: {...}, body: myPostBody, file: mockedFile  } as unknown as Request
    const myController = new MyController (...);
    const result = await myController.create(myPostBody, mockedRequest, mockedFile);
    await expect(result).rejects.toThrow();
  })
})
```

When I test the api by directly calling it, the validation pipe works fine. But when I test it in jest unit test, the validation pipe is not invoked at all.

Answer (score 1):

When you test your application using a testing framework like Jest, the decorators and their related pipes are not automatically invoked because you are not going through the actual NestJS request-response pipeline. Instead, you're just calling the controller method directly.

To test the pipes you can use [supertest](https://github.com/ladjs/supertest) - Super-agent driven library for testing node.js HTTP servers using a fluent API.

And then in your test use:

```
...
request(app.getHttpServer())
    .post('/...') 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipes, and other enhancers, will only fire when making an HTTP request. Just calling the controller method will not make the pipe, or other enhancers, work